# PHP JSON Removing HTML Tags

Tags: php, html, json

I'm working with an API that returns JSON and I'm using PHP to display it. Inside the JSON is HTML tags. I've been reading about the many ways you can remove them from the returned JSON but I have so many unique tags that I'm wondering what the easiest method would be? A lot of other questions seem to focus on specific tags and finding a solution to remove them. Is it possible to just remove all known HTML tags or do I need to program each one individually? If the answer is yes, what is the method for doing so?

Thank you for your time and input.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: I tried strip_tags but the returned information would still show the tags. All it seemed to do was prevent the browser from rendering them. Did I perhaps use it wrong?

[code] echo "Title:".strip_tags($results['title']); [/code]

Comment: Depends what is in `$results['title']`

Comment: Well, unless a] you control the API, or b] you can send a flag to the API to tell it to strip the HTML tags, you're gonna get what you get.  strip_tags() removes tags from what you get ... then you decide how to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply do this:

```
$data = json_decode($your_json_string, TRUE);

array_walk_recursive($data, function(&$v) { $v = htmlentities($v); });
```

or to remove tags completely

```
array_walk_recursive($data, function(&$v) { $v = strip_tags($v); });
```

Comment: array_walk_recursive($decoded_results, function(&$v) { $v = str_replace('&lt;p&gt;','&lt;/p&gt;','', $v); });

Comment: Your code gave me an idea and this worked pretty well, but I can't seem to get it to accept more than one input for the replace with ' '. Is it possible to add multiple items to str_replace?

Comment: Yes you can add multiple items like this:

Comment: like this for example: str_replace(array("\n\r","\n","\r"), '<br>', $data)